# Detect objects with OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm really new with `OpenCV`. I'm reading some tutorials and documentation in order to make my first little script.

I have an image and I want to `detect objects` on this one : street lamps, trashcans ...

**My image looks like :**

[image]

**I wrote this script :**

```
import cv2

img_filt = cv2.medianBlur(cv2.imread('ville.jpg',0), 5)
img_th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img_filt,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
img_filt, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_th, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

display = cv2.imshow("Objects",img_filt)
wait_time = cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But How I can display the picture result with rectangles ?

Thank you so much !

Comment: what objects do you want to detect? please clarify

Comment: You can use template matching to detect objects of same size and orientation. Here is the [link](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html#template-matching)

Comment: @nithin Yeah I'm sorry first time I'm using OpenCV. The goal is to detect street lamps, trashcans, .. on picture. I don't really find a very good tutorial to do that.

Comment: you need to draw the contours in order to see them : `cv2.drawContours(img_filt,contours,-1,(128,255,0),1)` . Although I would display them on the original image not the filtered one.

Comment: @VijayKalmath Thank you ! But it works only if I have images database right ?

Comment: @Roxanne Thank you too ! I will read properties about `drawContours`

Comment: @Andro Yes,you need to have the image that u want to find in the other image

Comment: @Andro welcome. please clarify in your original post what objects are you looking to determine. I recommend reading some paper about object detection also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess for object detection , which I personally use and recommend to all, is by using SIFT(Scale-Invariant Feature Transform) or SURF algorithm , but note that these algorithms are now patented , and no longer included in OpenCV 3, still availble in openCV2 , as good alternative to this I prefer to make use of ORB which is opensource implementaition of SIFT/SURF.

**Brute-Force Matching with SIFT Descriptors and Ratio Test**

here we use BFMatcher.knnMatch() to get k best matches. In this example, we will take k=2 so that we can apply ratio test explained by D.Lowe in his paper.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img1 = cv2.imread('box.png',0)          # queryImage
img2 = cv2.imread('box_in_scene.png',0) # trainImage

# Initiate SIFT detector
sift = cv2.SIFT()

# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

# BFMatcher with default params
bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(des1,des2, k=2)

# Apply ratio test
good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.75*n.distance:
        good.append([m])

# cv2.drawMatchesKnn expects list of lists as matches.
img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good,flags=2)

plt.imshow(img3),plt.show()
```

[image: An sample output for above code would be]

**Moving ahead with FLANN based Matcher**

> FLANN stands for Fast Library for Approximate Nearest Neighbors. It
>   contains a collection of algorithms optimized for fast nearest
>   neighbor search in large datasets and for high dimensional features.
>   It works more faster than BFMatcher for large datasets. We will see
>   the second example with FLANN based matcher.
>
> For FLANN based matcher, we need to pass two dictionaries which
>   specifies the algorithm to be used, its related parameters etc. First
>   one is IndexParams. For various algorithms, the information to be
>   passed is explained in FLANN docs. As a summary, for algorithms like
>   SIFT, SURF etc.

Sample code by using FLANN with SIFT:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img1 = cv2.imread('box.png',0)          # queryImage
img2 = cv2.imread('box_in_scene.png',0) # trainImage

# Initiate SIFT detector
sift = cv2.SIFT()

# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

# FLANN parameters
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)   # or pass empty dictionary

flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params,search_params)

matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)

# Need to draw only good matches, so create a mask
matchesMask = [[0,0] for i in xrange(len(matches))]

# ratio test as per Lowe's paper
for i,(m,n) in enumerate(matches):
    if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
        matchesMask[i]=[1,0]

draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0,255,0),
                   singlePointColor = (255,0,0),
                   matchesMask = matchesMask,
                   flags = 0)

img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches,None,**draw_params)



plt.imshow(img3,),plt.show()
```

See the result below:

[image]

**But what I recommend is, Brute-Force Matching with ORB Descriptors**

> In this example I used ORB with Bruteforce matcher, this code captures
>   frames from camera at realtime and computes the keypoints,descriptors
>   from input frames and compares it with the stored query image, by
>   doing the same , and returns the matching keypoint lengths, the
>   same can be applied on above code which uses SIFT algorithm instead of
>   ORB.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from imutils.video import WebcamVideoStream
from imutils.video import FPS

MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10

img1 = cv2.imread('input_query.jpg', 0)


orb = cv2.ORB()
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1, None)

webcam = WebcamVideoStream(src=0).start()
fps = FPS().start()

while True:
    img2 = webcam.read()
    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    cv2.imshow('',img2)
    if key == 1048603:
        break
    kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

    bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

    matches = bf.match(des1, des2)
    matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)  # compute the descriptors with ORB

    if not len(matches) > MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
        print "Not enough matches are found - %d/%d" % (len(matches), MIN_MATCH_COUNT)
        matchesMask = None

    #simg2 = cv2.polylines(img2,[np.int32(dst)],True,255,3, cv2.LINE_AA)

    print len(matches)
    #img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, matches[:10], None, flags=2)

    fps.update()

fps.stop()
```

> More descriptive video tutorial on this will be found here,
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZW3nrP2OyLQ and one more good thing is
>   it's opensource :
>   https://gitlab.com/josemariasoladuran/object-recognition-opencv-python.git

Comment: Thank you for your very long answer. It's a bit hard for me because I'm really new with this kind of librairies.

Comment: In my answer , i make use of standard CV algoritms in order to find best neraly mathichg keypoints in given input image/frame , and compare it with the image that we want to compare with, simply finding some object whos img we already have, and compare input img with the stored one, so in this case we only need the maximum no. of mathing keypoints that we know that can be found in the given i/p image.

Comment: check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZW3nrP2OyLQ it's opensource sa well, so clone it from here, git clone https://gitlab.com/josemariasoladuran/object-recognition-opencv-python.git , just make sure to run this in opencv3 , i guess this is exactly what you are looking for!

Comment: @Yes it's exactly what's I'm searching with just one difference : I don't have a video as startpoint but a picture. So I assume it's easier with picture ? I will look deeply your answer ;)

Comment: Yes you can modify the code, in order to compare picture only!, that code stream from webcam  and compare with camera frames, not with stealth picture as you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you ! I will search on this way ;)

Answer (score 0):

I posted the code as an answer but it just displays contours retrieved by your filters. Filters of that type are good for contour retrieving if your image is B&W and not super complex. Otherwise I think what are you looking for are bounding boxes around the objects. And that requires a bit more than some filters.

I also added matplotlib display because that's what you requested initially, but as you can it's a not very useful.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_orig = cv2.imread('ville.jpg',0)
img_filt = cv2.medianBlur(img_orig, 5)
img_th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img_filt,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_th, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

plt.imshow(img_orig)

cv2.drawContours(img_orig,contours,-1,(128,255,0),1)
display = cv2.imshow("Objects",img_orig)
wait_time = cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Additional helpful links:
http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html
http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

Later EDIT some useful literature that can get you started on advanced object detection you can find here: http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~fidler/teaching/2015/CSC2523.html

Note: this refers more to meaningful object detection and not just detection of simple contours that describe shapes.

Comment: I understand pretty well your script thank you ! I tried it with few modifications but I get this error : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image.py", line 17, in <module>
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_th, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: which version pf Python are you using? try calling it with 3 arguments as in your initial example. e.g: `image, contours, hierarchy = cv2...` in my Python 2.7 i can only use `cv2.findContours` with 2 arguments `contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours()`

Comment: @Andro Use this to overcome that error `contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]`

Comment: Strange because I'm using the same version as you. I will try some things and return the result if I get a solution ;)